# SQLite Select to compare two last orders in same row

Tags: sqlite

I have created a dataset "Orders" to test sqlite with structure

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
    OrderDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    CustomerID VARCHAR(20)
    OrderValue DECIMAL (8, 3)  NOT NULL
 );
```

---

I filled the table with sample data

```
ID Date       Customer Value($)
6  11-09-2019 Eva      6946.3 
7  11-10-2019 John      850.6
8  11-11-2019 Helen    9855.0 
9  11-12-2019 Maria     765.2
11 11-13-2019 Gui      1879.5  --< I removed ID 10 purposely
12 11-14-2019 Eric      600.0
13 11-15-2019 Paul    12890.1
```

How could I identify in same row both records 11 and 9, given the parameter :date, to represent the last sale of orderdate = `:date` and the immediately forward, or in case I changed record 9 to same date of 11, I get 8 (the last sale of last day)?

pseudo-code

```
select last 2 order where orderdate <= :date inner join (? a relation to put both in same row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Step one is to replace your `'MM-DD-YYYY'` date strings with ones that can be sorted - `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, for example (Then you can use the [date and time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) on them as well if needed). Since your `orderdate` column has a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but you're just showing the date and that not in the same format that uses, I assume you're inserting your dates manually instead of letting them be automatically generated on insert? The column names of your sample data table don't match up with the ones in your table definition either... that's confusing.

Anyways, since you said you want the values in the same row, the `lead()` window function comes into play (Requires Sqlite 3.25 or newer). Something like:

```
WITH cte AS
 (SELECT orderid, orderdate, customerid, ordervalue
       , lead(orderid, 1) OVER bydate AS next_id
       , lead(orderdate, 1) OVER bydate AS next_date
       , lead(customerid, 1) OVER bydate AS next_customer
       , lead(ordervalue, 1) OVER bydate AS next_value
  FROM orders
  WINDOW bydate AS (ORDER BY orderdate))
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE orderdate = :date;
```

gives for a `:date` of `'2019-11-12'`:

```
orderid     orderdate   customerid  ordervalue  next_id     next_date   next_customer  next_value
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -------------  ----------
9           2019-11-12  Maria       765.2       11          2019-11-13  Gui            1879.5
```

Comment: Thanks! Very Clear. But unfortunately, I need a solution without window function

Comment: @RicardodaRochaVitor please explain why you can use `window function` .